# When does aurelia's value binding propagate value changes?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, dom-events

I currently have a test where I have an input element with `value.bind="someProperty"` which works fine and correctly shows the value of that property in the input field.

However if I were to subscribe to the DOM `input` event on that field and when its invoked check the value of the property it is not the same as the DOM value, even if I were to do a delay of 100ms (via `setTimeout(checkPropertyValue, 100);`) the value is not always propagated to the model, so when exactly does the value get updated from the input field?

== Edit ==

Here is example code for the sort of thing that is occurring, a good point was raised in a passing conversation with someone that with view filters you may throttle `value` bindings so you cannot rely upon the model being updated straight away so you may have to listen out for model changes using `ObserverLocator`.

```
@customAttribute('some-atribute')
export class SomeAttribute
{
    @bindable someObjectWhichUsesVM;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        this.element.addEventListener("input", doSomethingWithModel);
    }

    doSomethingWithModel() {
        this.someObjectWhichUsesVM.doSomething();
    }
}
```

So the above code would check for input changes on an element (not the model bound) and then try to do something using data on the model, which wont be propagated.

I think I have already found the answer which is that I need to subscribe to the model for changes and basically make sure the change has occurred before I run the logic, but if there is a better way I am all ears.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the test, and the input in question?

Comment: Might have to use the Aurelia PAL library to properly listen to and trigger events (https://github.com/aurelia/pal-browser)